# App not running on older version of iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

I want my application to run on both `iOS 6` and `iOS 7`. I have already upgraded to `XCode 5,` so to see how my app runs on `ios 6`, i downloaded `ios SDK 6.1` and pasted it in the folder of XCode.app. I changed deployment target to ios `SDK 6.1`, the base SDK to `iOS SDK 6.1`. I have installed `simulator 6.1` too. But when i run my app, i get several errors..
like

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:53:24: 'UIAccelerometer' is unavailable: not available on OS X
```

All errors are similar to this one. I don't know why the app is trying to run on mac OS X..

Comment: I'm not sure how all you have hacked Xcode. But the correct way to do this with XC5 is set the SDK to 7, your deployment target to 6 or 6.1 and install the 6.x Simulator. Set the sim to 6.x, build and run.

Comment: you'd better use Xcode4.6 to run ios6.1 simulator,or Xcode4.5 to run ios6.0

Comment: @BergQuester: I did not hack XCode. Everything else i was doing was correct, but what i was doing wrong was setting base SDK to 6.1. I changed it to 7 again, and viola..!! Thanks a lot for your comment.

Comment: "i downloaded ios SDK 6.1 and pasted it in the folder of XCode.app"  You are modifying the Xcode app bundle into something that Apple has not tested and does not support. Some do not consider this a hack, I certainly do. Glad to hear you got it working though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why you done this all if you only want to run your app on both iOS 6 and 7.

You can see your app running like on iOS 6 device by simply running the app on iOS 6 simulator with XCode 5 and iOS7 Sdk. You dont have to change your deployment target anyways.

Even if you want to see your XIb in iOS6 pattern,you can do that too in XCode 5. If you want to see that, please revert me i will tell you that too. Or if you want something else, please tell us more precisely. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you can run other apps on your simulator.

What about your error description - UIAccelerometer is deprecated in iOS 5. I think you try to run old application.